# pigeonhole principle, for a chessboard problem.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, chessboard

assume we have a chess-board 8 by 8 squares.

lets define the "prince" play tool:

the "prince" can move from any given square to any other square the Queen can move to or to any other square the Horse can move to.

means that if from some square on the chess board the set off all squares the Queen can go to is Q = {$x_1,...,x_m$} and the set off all squares the Horse can go to is H = {$y_1,...,y_n$} than the set off all squares the Prince can go to is P = Q $\cup$ H.

prove that for 7 pieces of "princes" on the board there must be 2 that will Threaten each other.

---

im' not sure if the statement is still correct for even 6 pieces but i know that for less than 6 pieces it isn't.

Comment: Do you *have* to prove this using the pigeonhole principle? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Note that a prince ends up attacking all of the 24 squares around it with itself being in the middle of a $5 \times 5$ square. So think of it how you can place such $5 \times 5$ squares on a board, noting of course that a prince placed along the side of the board threatens less than $24$ actual squares of the board (so it is still not an easy problem this way, but maybe a little easier nevertheless...)

Comment: @nedgrekerzberg Oh, and here I started to doubt the usefulness of my hint! ... I tried thinking about the problem this way and while I quickly found a valid board with 6 princes, I *almost* found one with 7 princes, with only long diagonal preventing it from being valid .. but those long diagonals aren't really being addressed by using these 5x5 squares.  Also, I am still not sure how you would use the pigeonhole principle for this problem ... maybe I am missing something ... Did you find an actual proof it's not possible?